# how to position absolute div to bottom in absolute div

Tags: html, css

I want to position a div, which has `position: absolute` at the bottom in another div, which also has `position: absolute`. For some reason I can't achieve it and it drives me crazy :-/ So I was hoping I could get some help here.

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6q7qdvms/1/) - Its the element `<div class="item__info-details">` I want at the bottom.

Maybe my markup is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give position to `child div`

as you want div in bottom on hover then `.item__info-details > div` by this you can get. Just give `position:absolute`  and `bottom:0` and you are done.

```
.item__info-details {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            padding: 0 20px;
}

.item__info-details > div {position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

Don't forget to remove top:110px and width and height from `.item__info-details` as no need.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6q7qdvms/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of useless tags here.

This is all you need:

```css
.item__info-details {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/okud5k80/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Please change in the css and replace with the below:

```
.item__info-details {
          position: absolute;
        top: 110px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        padding: 0 20px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
```

}

Replace to:

```
.item__info-details {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        padding: 0 20px;
        width: 100%;
```

}